# CakePHP read in hasMany through relationship

Tags: cakephp

Trying to display related data from a hasMany through table. It's finding the joinModel but not extending to the other table's data.

**Item Model**:

```
class Item extends AppModel {
public $name = 'Item';
    public $belongsTo = array('Category');
    public $hasMany = array('GroclistItem');
}
```

**Groclist Model**:

```
class Groclist extends AppModel {
public $name = 'Groclist';
    public $belongsTo = array('Category');
    public $hasMany = array('GroclistItem');
}
```

**GroclistItem Model**:

```
class GroclistItem extends AppModel {
public $name = 'GroclistItem';
    public $belongsTo = array('Groclist', 'Item');
    public $useTable = 'groclists_items';
}
```

**GroclistController View Action**:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid list', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('groclist', $this->Groclist->read(null, $id));
}
```

**Debug of $groclist**:

```
app\View\Groclists\view.ctp (line 80)
Array
(
[Groclist] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => This Week
        [user_id] => 
        [sunday] => Pizza
        [monday] => Scallops
        [tuesday] => Stuffed Mushrooms
        [wednesday] => Mustard Chicken with Daulphanois Potatoes
        [thursday] => Sizzling Chicken and Cheese
        [friday] => Walkabout Soup with Beer Bread
        [saturday] => Paradise Indian
        [created] => 2011-09-15 14:42:55
        [modified] => 2012-02-19 16:51:00
    )

[GroclistItem] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 18
                [item_id] => 24
                [groclist_id] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 17
                [item_id] => 23
                [groclist_id] => 3
            )

    )

)
```

I would like the GroclistItem array to display the item data which should be a grocery list item such as Diet Coke or Soap. It's finding the correct associations in there.

Comment: Why do you have an Item model and a GroclistItem model? If GroclistItem is a specific type of Item, then surely Groclist should have many Items then?

Comment: your GroclistItem Table look like a joinTable for a hasAndBelongsToMany relation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GroclistController View Action:

```
public function view($id = null) {
if (!$id) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid list', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
$this->Groclist->recursive =2;
$this->set('groclist', $this->Groclist->read(null, $id));
}
```

Comment: This method works but after adding 15 items, it is now doing 32 database queries taking around 8 ms. My question is how well will this scale?

Comment: Then You have to use containable : http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1323/Containable    or   use unBindModel: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly